# Persistent childs in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a simple application that has a Parent and Child model. The problem is that the parents are often updated through reading a text file, but the Children for each of the Parents are updated through the web-app. So how can I keep the Children attached to each of their Parents since each time I read the files I create new Parents?

Comment: Need more details. Say you have `parent1` which has two children `ch1`, `ch2`. Now you read a file and create a new parent `parent2`. But still `ch1` and `ch2` is connected with `parent1`. And seems you can add more children to `parent2` from web-app. So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious thing would be to not re-create the parents every time you parse the file (is that possible?). Using `first_or_create`[(link)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object) that shouldn't be to painful...